# Sorting a list in Java the same way, ids appear in an array

Tags: java, list, sorting, guava

I have an array with ids

```
  [2,3,1]
```

From an external rest Service, I'll get a List with UserObjects. These userObjects contains userids (1 or 2 or 3)

I now would like to sort the list in the same order, The userids appear in my array. Maybe it's helpful to say that I am able to use guava (v15) in my code.
Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%3CT%3E%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int[] ids = ...
List<UserObject> userObjects = ...
Collections.sort(userObjects, new Comparator<UserObject>() {
  public int compare(UserObject a, UserObject b) {
    return Ints.compare(
        Ints.indexOf(ids, a.getId()),
        Ints.indexOf(ids, b.getId()));
  }
});
```

Comment: It seems I've written more or less the same in my answer, but I'm suprised by Ints.compare(int,int)... is there any difference between that and `return a-b;`?

Comment: If indexOf could return a large negative value, then you would have to worry about overflow.  But the least it can return is -1, and I don't think it can return Integer.MAX_VALUE (because arrays can't be that large), so you're probably ok.  I would still use Ints.compare because it says what it does.  It compares.  The minus sign doesn't explain itself quite as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays.sort is your friend : [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(short[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28short%5B%5D%29)

Or if you want to sort a collection of complex types, make sure the complex type (user?) implements [comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and [compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29).

Or more likely in this, you'll need to supply a custom [comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), which allows sorting by in different orders [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22987813/106261).

Comment: I don't want to sort the array, I want to sort the list (the same way, the userids appear in the array)

Comment: @Christian second part of answer, or actualyl third part

Answer (score 0):

You can use Collections.sort(List,Comparator), with a comparator like this:

```
class MyComp implements Comparator<UserObject> {

    private int[] ref;

    public MyComp(int [] reference) {
        this.ref=reference;
    }

    public compare(UserObject o1, UserObjects o2) {
        return Ints.indexOf(ref,o1.id) - Ints.indexOf(ref,o2.id);
    }
}
```